# Сould you say what is the core, 1-3 main meaning for ‘to get’

Tags: word-usage

Once one Englishman said me that ‘to engage’ means – ‘get into contact’ in any its meanings and after that I began using it easier.
I want to say that any dictionary gives many (dozen and more like for ‘to engage’) meanings for a word and learners get stuck to memorize a lot of different meanings for one word.
In this system could you say what is the core, 1-3 main meanings for ‘to get’.

Answer (score 0):

The word "to get" by itself is simple: it means to obtain.

However, "get" is often used as a phrasal verb, as is the case here.  There are many such phrasal verbs: **get into**, **get lost**, **get rid of**, **get on with**, **get along with**, **get away with**, **get by**, **get off**, **get over**, **get up**, etc. These uses are quite distinct from each other and also very common. You will not be able to get away with (see what I did there?) learning 1-3 uses of the word get if you intend to learn English.

Instead of thinking of "get" as a single word with a bunch of different meanings, think of each phrasal verb as a different word that happens to have a space in it.  The phrasal verb your friend taught you is "get into," which means enter or establish.

Comment: Where, in what dictionary are there such meanings as 'establish' for 'get into' or it is just feeling of a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking what is the primary meaning of *to get*, it would be "to receive":

> The boy **got** a puppy for his birthday.

"Receive" is very broad, in that it can apply not just to *things*, but to *services and concepts*, and even *intentions, qualities, emotions, or physical positions*.  In this sense:

> They **got tired** as it became late

implies that they gradually "received" the feeling of being tired. This variation, that means "to become" or "to grow" is quite common:

> The children all **got sick** at the same time, but the youngest **got better** first.
>
> The more she practiced, the better she **got** at drawing.

Meanwhile:

> They **got out** of class at three

can suggest that they "received" the quality of being outside the classroom.  Still, with some of these kind of uses of *get*, it's not as simple.  For example:

> I told the boys to **get off** of the dangerous rocks.

which is more in the form of a *command*, ordering the boys to *get into* ("receive the quality of being in") a different position.  Similarly:

> Ralphie!  Where are you?  **Get over** here, dog!

is a command for the dog to move toward the owner. In this it's difficult to say who is "receiving" what.

There is also *get close to, get away from, get up, get down, get in, get under*, and many more.  In practice the use of *get* has many nuances, and each of its [phrasal verbs](https://7esl.com/phrasal-verbs-with-get/) should be learned as separate vocabulary, not to mention [all the various idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get).

Comment: Very useful. I don't understand 'get off' means 'get into' in 'I told the boys to get off of the dangerous rocks.'  can you clarify this. And do you consider that in phrasial verbs 'get' does not mean 'receive'?

Comment: Andrey could you explain (as you explained 'get') what is core meaning for 'put'?

Comment: @Vitaly I think at a certain point the model doesn't work and "get" doesn't always mean "receive". But for the most part it should be okay. In any case "get off" means "to move from an position on something,  **into** another position off of that thing."

Comment: @Vitaly  As for "put", you should probably ask that as a separate question.